# select distinct mongodb C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have to select distinct records from my simple mongo db database. 
I have many simple records these records looks like this :

```
{"word":"some text"}
```

My code is very simple.

```
    const string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
    var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

    MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
    MongoDatabase database = server.GetDatabase("text8");
    MongoCollection<Element> collection = database.GetCollection<Element>("text8");
    MongoCursor<Element> words = (MongoCursor<Element>)collection.FindAll();
```

But I have't idea how to select distinct word's from database. 
Could someone can give me some advice ?

Comment: Do you want to split your records into separate words and return these distinct words or simply return distinct values for `word` key?

Comment: No, my intention id to select unrepeatable words from collection.

Answer (score 12):

MongoDB API has a [`distinct`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct/#dbcmd.distinct) aggregation command, which returns distinct values found for a specified key in a collection. You can also use it from [C# Driver](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/2.2/html/Overload_MongoDB_Driver_MongoCollection_Distinct.htm):

```
var distinctWords = collection.Distinct("word");
```

where `collection` - is an instance from your example. This query will return all distinct values of `word` field in the collection.

Also, as @JohnnyHK mentioned in comment, you can use [linq approach](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/driver/crud/linq/#distinct), since it is supported by C# driver:

```
var distinctWords = collection.AsQueryable<Element>().Select(e => e.Word).Distinct();
```

Comment: The LINQ interface provided by the C# driver executes its queries via MongoDB, so it's not retrieving all records and then filtering them in code and is typically just as efficient.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, thanks for your correction. I actually thought about support of linq by C# driver but wasn't entirely sure. I've corrected answer.

Answer (score 3):

this work´s for me

```
Collection.Distinct<string>("ColumnNameForDistinct", FilterDefinition<T>.Empty).ToListAsync()
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be to make "word" an index on this db.
Then using some linq to query it in a simple expression:
    var res = col.Query().Select(e => e.word).Distinct();

This would result in reading all words from the index.

Answer (score 1):

The [`MongoCollection.Distinct` Method (String) V2.0](http://MongoCollection.Distinct%20Method%20(String)) is **Legacy**

for [new version API like 2.4](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_Distinct__1.htm) use:

```
FieldDefinition<yueyun.land,string> field = "FirstName";
var bx = _yueyunlands.Distinct<string>(field, Builders<yueyun.land>.Filter.Empty).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter first and get distinct afterwards and also do all of these at MongoDB side, you can use the following example. 
In this example I applied a filter, got distinct values and finally got count:

```
        var filter = Builders<Logs>.Filter.Ne(x => x.Id, null);
        var count = collection.Distinct(x => x.Id, filter).ToList().Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB doesn't have a built in operator to split a string of words from a query as there's not a way to split a string, then run a "distinct" operation on it.

One option would be to create a [MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) and do the split in the MapReduce code and count each word. You can't do this with just C# code.

A second, and possibly simpler option would be to pre-split the field into words so that you could use one of the [distinct](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) operators:

```
{ "word": [ "some", "text"] }
```

Then:

```
dbCollection.Distinct("word");
```

This would of course work if you just want to treat the entire string as a "word" rather than each word separately
.
MapReduce's aren't real-time ... the pseudo-code would be:

```
map = function() {
  var splits = this.word.split(' ');
  for(var i = 0, l = splits.length; i < l; i++) {
     emit(splits[i], 1);
  }
}

reduce = function(word, vals) {
   var count = 0;
   for(var i=0, l=vals.length; i < l; i++) {
       count += vals[i];
   }
   return count;
}
```

When you run the MapReduce, it would be a collection of the number of occurrences of each word.