# Query unique year from MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, database

I am looking to select distinct years from a MongoDB. I can do queries based on greater than or less than time, with the query returning full date objects, but in this case I want to get a list of strings that are unique years from the field `timestamp`.

```
_dbClient = new MongoClient();
_dbServer = _dbClient.GetServer();
_dbDatabase = _dbServer.GetDatabase("test");
_collectionSamples = _dbDatabase.GetCollection<Sample>("samples");

var samples = _collectionSamples.findAll().Distinct(...);
```

And the class I am querying is

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
[DataContract]
public class NeuralSample
{
    [DataMember]
    public ObjectId _id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
    public DateTime timestamp
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public float alpha_low
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I believe that in Distinct I need to use the field "timestamp" though that will return all timestamps (tens of thousands of results) instead of just the years (1 to 2 results).

I can do it (or at least with a couple iterations pull out the data I want) via the command line interface using

```
db.samples.aggregate([
    { $group : 
        { _id : 
            { year : { $year : "$timestamp" } }, 
            total : { $sum : 1 } 
        }
    }])
```

which gives me an array of all the years that I had samples in, along with a list of counts. For years, the highest level query, this is great, but at some point I will want to query for the months with samples in year 'x', all using the C# driver. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've looked around SO and this was the closest question I could find to mine

[Select Distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755783/select-distinct-mongodb-c-sharp)

Thanks!

Comment: the aggregation query is the correct approach.  why would it be a problem for months?  Just use $match to filter first to dates in year "x" and then do the same $group with $month.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I could do the aggregate, but I can't seem to get it to work in the C# driver and I couldn't find any useful examples of where to apply 2 filters, the year and the month, to the aggregate.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by two filters - wouldn't you just be doing a date range compare?  $match takes basically the same syntax as find.

Comment: I was able to get it by a somewhat hackish workaround, for finding months using C# to start querying at the first month and day in a specific year and taking one element. If result.timestamp.month is less than 12, add one to the month and start searching from there.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking to group by month of year. If so the following from the shell will work

```
db.samples.aggregate([
    { $group : { 
        _id : { year : { $year : "$timestamp" }, month : { $month : "$timestamp" }}, 
        total : { $sum : 1 } 
    }},
    { $sort : {"_id.year" : 1, "_id.month" : 1}}
])
```

The equivalent aggregation in c# would be

```
var result = _collectionSamples.Aggregate(new BsonDocument
    {    
        { "$group" , new BsonDocument 
            {
                { "_id", new BsonDocument 
                    {
                        { "year", new BsonDocument("$year", "$timestamp") }, 
                        { "month", new BsonDocument("$month", "$timestamp") }
                    }
                },
                { "total", new BsonDocument("$sum", 1) }
            }
        }
    });
```