# MongoDb and F#: How to select distinct values?

Tags: mongodb, f#, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using the latest (at the time of writing) version (2.8) of the C# MongoDb driver.
I am using it from F#.
I want to select the distinct values of a field in a collection.

From [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35725113/c-sharp-mongodb-distinct-query-syntax), the following does not work:

```
let client = new MongoClient(connString)
let db = client.GetDatabase("AirQuality")
let col = db.GetCollection<ReadingValue>("ReadingValue")
let res = col.DistinctAsync<string>("SensorName","{}")
```

The type `string` is not compatible with the type `FieldDefinition<ReadingValue,string>`.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50827849/3760519), the following does not work either

```
let fd : FieldDefinition<ReadingValue, string> = "" :> FieldDefinition<ReadingValue, string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# you can implicitly convert from string to `FieldDefinition<T>` ([class](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_FieldDefinition_2.htm) implements implicit operator). Since types conversion works in a different way in F# you can use [StringFieldDefinitionClass](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_StringFieldDefinition_2.htm)

```
let field = new StringFieldDefinition<ReadingValue, string>("SensorName")
let result = col.Distinct<string>(field, Builders<ReadingValue>.Filter.Empty)
```